# How to change the background colour of a button when it is pressed in Python, Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I am currently learning Kivy, and cannot figure out how to change the background colour of the button when it is clicked on. I know the colour changes by default to a shade of blue, but I do not want this to happen. I have the following code...

-----Python Script----

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class NotesScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PaintingScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CalculatorScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ContactsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class DictionairyScreen(Screen):
    pass



kv = Builder.load_file("multi_pages.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

----.kv file----

```
WindowManager:
    HomeScreen:
    NotesScreen:
    PaintingScreen:
    CalculatorScreen:
    ContactsScreen:
    DictionairyScreen:


<HomeScreen>:
    name: "home"

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Notes"
            pos_hint: {"x": .325, "top": .875}
            size_hint: .35, .12
            font_size: 20
            background_color: -1, 1, 1, 1




        Button:
            text: "Painting"
            pos_hint: {"x": .325, "top": .725}
            size_hint: .35, .12
            font_size: 20
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            background_color: -1, -1, -1, 0.3
               
            on_press:
                print("Clicked")

            on_release:
                print("Released")

            on_state:
                print("my current state is {}".format(self.state))
                




        Button:
            text: "Calculator"
            pos_hint: {"x": .325, "top": .575}
            size_hint: .35, .12
            font_size: 20

        Button:
            text: "Contacts"
            pos_hint: {"x": .325, "top": .425}
            size_hint: .35, .12
            font_size: 20

        Button:
            text: "Dictionairy"
            pos_hint: {"x": .325, "top": .275}
            size_hint: .35, .12
            font_size: 20
```

Any and all help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this in the future, I've sorted it, you have to do it in Python. Below is my code...

----.py file---

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class WindowOne(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(Screen, ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file("style.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

----.kv file----

```
WindowManager:
    WindowOne:

<WindowOne>:
    name: "Home"
    btn: btn
    btn2: btn2

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            text: "Hello world"
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.4}
            background_normal: ""
            background_color: 1, .5, 1, 1
            id: btn

            on_press:
                print("Pressed button 1")
                btn.background_color = RGB = .1, -.4, 1, 1

            on_release:
                print("Released button 1")       
                btn.background_color = RGB = 1, .5, 1, 1      
            
        
        Button:
            text: "Goodbye world"
            size_hint: .2, .2
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top": 0.4}
            background_normal: ""
            background_color: .3, 1, -.7, 1
            id: btn2

            on_press:
                print("Pressed button 2")
                btn2.background_color = RGB = 1, -1, -.7, 1

            on_release:
                print("Released button 2")
                btn2.background_color = RGB = .3, 1, -.7, 1
```